# WCF - Create custom Attribute to modify property

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

After reading [this article](http://www.gitshah.com/2015/02/how-to-automatically-set-datetimekind.html), I would like to use custom attribute to modify data exposed in the WCF webservice. But in the article there is a method called in EF.

Is it possible for an attribute to alter data about property it is attached ? I would like to declare and enter in a method for each property having the annotation and set the DateTimeKind

Here is an example of code I began to write :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DateTimeKindAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly DateTimeKind _kind;

    public DateTimeKindAttribute(DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        _kind = kind;
    }
}
```

Why the `attribute` class does not exposed a method called to modify the data ?

Comment: Consider using aspects and AOP, aspect oriented programming for this scenario. Postsharp forecample offers the LocationInterceptionAspect demoed here: http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-7-Interception-Aspects-e28093-Part-1

Answer (score 0):

Your ServiceContract needs to be translated into a WSDL. Prove a DateTimeKind as a property of a data contract. Then adjust the properties to support the conversion you want to offer.